# Импорт библиотек apache

Tags: java, apache, intellij-idea

Как правильно находить библиотеки, которых нет в стандартных. Например я хочу использовать *Apache* `httpclient`, но для того, что бы их использовать нужно скачивать эти библиотеки.

Можно ли сделать как-нибудь, что-бы библиотеки, которых нет, автоматически импортировались как стандартные?

Что для этого нужно?

Comment: используйте maven

Comment: используйте gradle

Comment: ужаснулся я, лучше бы я не знал про эти вещи о_О их же настраивать мучится устанешь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте любой фреймворк для автоматической сборки, например maven

Comment: Вроде gradle лучше, если проект не совсем стандартный. например gui javafx вместо swing. Или не так? Посмотрел я курс по gradle и ничего не понял, слишком много непонятной информации =_=

Comment: Что лучше я не могу судить, к тому же gradle не использовал, знаю лишь, что в Maven это сделать весьма просто

Comment: разобрался с maven, оказывается не все так сложно, как я думал. все более менее даже легко.